# c++ - Exception thrown: write access violation. this was nullptr

Tags: c++, exception

I am trying to define a new object of struct type:

#### header.h

```c
class myclass {

public:
    myclass();
    ~myclass();

    typedef struct G {
        float s;
        int n;
    };

    G* my_object;
};
```

#### cfile.cpp

```
myclass::myclass(){}
myclass::~myclass(){}

void myclass::initialization() {

    my_object = new G[12];

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        my_object[i].s = 0.0;
        my_object[i].n = 0;
    }
}
```

In the **cfile.cpp** at line `my_object = new G[12];` I get this exception:

> Exception thrown: write access violation.
> this was nullptr.

How can I fix this problem?

Also, is there a better way to define this kind of object?

Comment: The error is not inside your code, but occurs call the initialisation function on a null pointer: `myclass* p = nullptr; p->initialisation();`

Comment: Some other points: You don't need `typedef` for the struct, and actually it's not used correctly anyway (you don't specify another name for struct G, would look like `typedef struct G { } GG;`). Instead of initialising the structs in a loop you should rather provide a constructor for `G`.

Comment: If `initialization` is just intended for constructing `myclass`, then you should drop it, too, in favour of a constructor again. Otherwise (if you want to call it later on again on the same object), you must consider the array already existing. Not deleting it will result in a memory leak. All alike if you don't provide a destructor deleting the array again. Better variant would be a smart pointer, covers both object destruction and re-assignment (`std::unique_ptr<G[]> my_objects;`). Even simpler: Use a `std::vector<G>`...

Comment: Back to struct G: As alternative to constructor, since C++11 you can provide default initialisers, too: `struct G { float s = .0f; int n = 0; };` (you can even combine default initialisers and constructor; if constructor assigns a value, too, then it has precedence over the default initialiser).

Comment: @Aconcagua thank you for the helpful tips. As you mentioned the problem was in the main function. I changed `myclass* p{}` to `myclass* p= new myclass;` and it worked.

Comment: @Aconcagua Do you mean it is better to use constructor rather than default initialiser for this case?

Comment: Either is fine, choose whichever you prefer. I grew up with C++ when default initialisers didn't exist yet, that's why constructor is first thing to come into my mind... Sometimes, though, you need to do a bit more than just simple assignments, *then* you'll need the constructor, the same if you want to have parameters.